# Where I can get some sample profile pictures?

Tags: resources

Any sites similar to [uifaces.com](http://uifaces.com)?

Comment: This might be better suited on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Have a camera phone? Have a co-worker? If so, you're set.

Comment: Here you go! http://randomuser.me/

Comment: Here you go! https://diverseui.com

Answer (score 2):

So you are looking for a place to get sample candid, amateur-created pictures?  Use some of your own or take some.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check a stock photography site. There are free (sxc.hu) and paid sites that provide high res pictures of all varieties.